# Which cassandra python pacakge to be used?

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am new to Cassandra and just started to use Cassandra with python.

What is the difference among the following 3 python packages

```
1. cql
2. pycassa
3. cassandra-driver
```

Are these 3 serve the same purpose?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pycassa is an older python driver that is thrift based while [python-driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) is a newer CQL3 driver based on cassandra's binary protocol. Thrift isn't going away but it has become a legacy API in cassandra so *my advice* going forward is to use the newer python driver.

I wrote a [blog](http://www.lyubentodorov.co.uk/blog/2014/04/16/python-driver-overview-using-twissandra/) that you might find helpful, which uses the [Twissandra](https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra) example application with the DataStax python-driver to provide an overview of CRUD and using prepared statements etc.

As for [cql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cql) I haven't had any experience with this one, but the homepage of the project says it all:

> This driver has been deprecated. Please use python-driver https://github.com/datastax/python-driver instead

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am facing compiler problems with installing blist (python cassandra driver prerequisite), is it mandatory to install that software?